# How to prevent a user from entering a value on a selector field for a value not in the selector list [Acumatica]

Tags: acumatica

Is there a property in the ASPX control to prevent the users from typing a value?  Or the property is in the DAC field declaration?  In this case, the user must only select from the list of values, provided by the selector.  I do not want them to enter a value manually.  This is a key field in a custom screen (if this matters?)

Answer (score 0):

The selector attribute by default will validate the value entered by a user  unless you have `ValidateValue = false` on your selector.

This selector for example will allow users to select/enter any value.

```
[PXSelector(typeof(ARContact.contactID), ValidateValue = false)]
```

If you make the selector like so, then only the values from the list are allowed to be selected/entered.

```
[PXSelector(typeof(ARContact.contactID))]
```